# React testing error when wrapping a Component in a Memory Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-testing-library

I am testing on React, and I want to see the detail of a page and I need to pass a param in the path, so I was searching and I need to wrap my component in a MemoryRouter and a Route, but I still getting an error:

MemoryRouter:

```
component = render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/characters/1009368']}>
      <Route path="characters/:id">
        <CharacterDetail />
      </Route>
    </MemoryRouter>
  </Provider>,
);
```

And this is the error that I got:

```
console.error
  Error: Uncaught [Error: A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your <Route> in a <Routes>.]
```

What can I do?

Comment: ...wrap your Route in a Routes?

Answer (score 3):

The error message is pretty straightforward, wrap your `Route` components in a `Routes` component.

For example:

```
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/welcome" element={<Welcome />} />
        <Route path="/game" element={<Game />} />
        <Route path="/leaderboard" element={<Leaderboard />} />
      </Routes>
```

for more details, visit [here](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v6-pre/#introducing-routes)

Comment: Ohh I see, It was so easy and I was struggling with that jajaj thank you!